# Why is getElementsByClassName returning undefined in React's functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, getelementsbyclassname

In one of my functional components in an application using React.js, calling getElementsByClassName returns 'undefined', when clearly, there is a section tag with the className.

```
import React from 'react';
import Expansion from './Expansion';

// ExpansionView refers to the container box that displays individual expansion boxes
const ExpansionView = (props) => {

const validExpansion = [
    "Classic", "Naxxramas", "Goblins vs Gnomes", "Blackrock Mountain", "The Grand Tournament", 
    "The League of Explorers", "Whispers of the Old Gods", "One Night in Karazhan", "Mean Streets of Gadgetzan",
    "Journey to Un'Goro", "Knights of the Frozen Throne", "Kobolds & Catacombs", "The Witchwood", 
    "The Boomsday Project", "Rastakhan's Rumble", "Rise of Shadows", "Saviors of Uldum", "Descent of Dragons",
    "Galakrond's Awakening", "Ashes of Outland", "Scholomance Academy", "Madness At The Darkmoon Faire",
    "Forged in the Barrens", "United in Stormwind",
];
// length is 24


//create a function that will filter by validExpansion and create an Expansion component
const expansionGenerator = (props) => {
    const expansionViewTag = document.getElementsByClassName('expansionView')[0];


    for (let i = 0; i < validExpansion.length; i += 1) {
        expansionViewTag.appendChild(
           <Expansion key={props.expansion[validExpansion[i]]} selectExpansion={props.selectExpansion}/>
        )
    }
    return 
    // return <Expansion expansion={props.expansion} selectExpansion={props.selectExpansion}/>
}



return(
    
    <section className='expansionView'>
         {expansionGenerator(props)}   
        </section>
        

    )

}
 
export default ExpansionView;
```

2 reasons for the loop:

1. Not ideal to write  24 times in return statement.(thus want to append)
2. Assign props for every , and props will simply be each element in the array validExpansion.

Please help me with a valid solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you are initially rendering and React hasn't committed anything to the DOM the `className='expansionView'` classname doesn't exist in the `document` yet.

In React it is an anti-pattern to directly manipulate the DOM, like getting an element by id/class/etc and appending children nodes to it.

If you want to loop over an array structure and render JSX then use a map function to iterate the array and map each element to some JSX.

```
const ExpansionView = ({ expansion, selectExpansion }) => {
  const validExpansion = [
    "Classic", "Naxxramas", "Goblins vs Gnomes", "Blackrock Mountain", "The Grand Tournament", 
    "The League of Explorers", "Whispers of the Old Gods", "One Night in Karazhan", "Mean Streets of Gadgetzan",
    "Journey to Un'Goro", "Knights of the Frozen Throne", "Kobolds & Catacombs", "The Witchwood", 
    "The Boomsday Project", "Rastakhan's Rumble", "Rise of Shadows", "Saviors of Uldum", "Descent of Dragons",
    "Galakrond's Awakening", "Ashes of Outland", "Scholomance Academy", "Madness At The Darkmoon Faire",
    "Forged in the Barrens", "United in Stormwind",
  ];

  return (
    <section className='expansionView'>
      {validExpansion.map(value => (
        <Expansion key={expansion[value]} selectExpansion={selectExpansion}/>
      ))}   
    </section>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I were to map it like you coded, it will return a copy of the array(with mapped elements, of course). I am looking to write multiple <Expansion/> in section tag using for loop, not an array whose elements are <Expansion/>. Will an array work the same? I cannot visualize/test the idea yet because I have to edit css to visualize, thus asking you first. Thanks

Comment: @JoonK Can you clarify what you mean by "write multiple `<Expansion />` in section tag using for loop"? If by that you want a bunch of `Expansion` components rendered into the DOM then "returning an array whose elements are `<Expansion />`" is the way React does it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I meant "calling multiple Expansion component(which is a direct child) 24 times(length of validExpansion array)". I am surprised we can use arrays. I have not seen it in the official document when I read all of the main concept part and hooks long time ago. If you could point me to a source so that I can learn more, it'd be great. If not, thank you, your answer allows me to code further :)

Comment: @JoonK It could be an array with thousands of values to map, React/JSX can handle it. A good place to start might be the [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) docs, which goes over some React basics with rendering/returning arrays.